# Reference request for a divisibility property of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: reference-request, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

Define the Fibonacci numbers $F_n$ by $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ and initial values $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1.$

I would like to get a reference for the following result:

If $p$ is a prime number with  $p \equiv  \pm 2\bmod 5$ then $p$ divides $F_{p+1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what a reference request is, but does this suffice: http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/4-3/halton.pdf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Fibonacci Numbers Modulo $p$](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Ebrianrl/notes/fibonacci.pdf) by Brian Lawrence (Theorem 4.4), or in (1.5) from [Some formulae for the Fibonacci sequence with generalizations](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/7-2/andrews.pdf) by George H. Andrews. The latter cites G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright, An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, 1960, page 150. Here is a screen copy (and a [copy](https://blngcc.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/hardy-wright-theory_of_numbers.pdf) of the book):

[image: Theorem 180, prime division of Fibonacci numbers]

Comment: Yes, it's Theorem 180 from the 4th edition of Hardy and Wright's book. You can find it on archive.org.

Comment: Nice reminder, I have added a snapshot, which I forgot to do sooner

Answer (score 0):

On this topic, maybe someone knows of an easy way to use Hardy and Wright to show this result that a student of mine has discovered independently on her own: for $p$ prime, $F_p \equiv 1$ mod $p$ if $p \equiv 1,4$ mod 5, and $F_p \equiv -1$ mod $p$ if $p \equiv 2,3$ mod 5. In other words, $F_p \equiv \left(\frac{p}{5}\right)$ for $\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)$ the Jacobi symbol.

I can't quite see how to get there from Hardy and Wright's Theorem 180.